# Something came from the sea. What does it attack first?

Tags: sea-creatures, carnivorous, kaiju

There is some sort of carnivorous mega-creature. What it is  doesn't matter. What does matter is that it can kill pretty much anything. Imagine a mini-kaiju. Like, only the size of a double-decker bus or two. If it wanted, it could take on an elephant, if any were nearby. Also, its skin is about as bullet-resistant as that of a tank.

Humans aren't aware of it.

Then, one night, a few hundred or maybe more of these pop up all around the world, crawl out of the sea, kill and eat something, and crawl back. Reasons for doing this are unknown.

My question is, what is the most likely first target of these mini-kaiju? Cows? Humans? Sea-birds by the dozen?

Likeliness should be from the point of view of statistics, about what creatures are most likely to be around in these places.

Of course there are going at least a few casualties from a whole bunch of species, but what species is going to be hit the hardest?

An additional thing of note is that it is not a turtle-roosting or hatching da or anything like that.

Comment: Are the attacks targeted (ie part of a co-ordinated assault on humans or land in general, either among the kaiju themselves, or by a controlling force)?  Or are they acting in an animalistic fashion, following some (xeno)biological imperative?

Comment: It depends what they are partial to real doesn't it? They may gorge on whatever creature they come across first or they might be a bit choosier, how can we tell?

Comment: More to their point, what is their motivation for attacking? If it's food, there has to be a reason for why they don't just go for fish.

Comment: If you get one answer for "cows" and another for "humans", how would you be able to determine which answer is better? This is completely open ended and on top of that it's not even a world-building question. "What happens in my story" is off-topic.

Comment: @Stephen biological imperative. Maybe they are being crowded out from underwater, and are heading for shallower areas.

Comment: @Slarty Not particularly partial to anything when they first come ashore. If there is any data about carnivores being more partial to something or other after tasting it, that is global for all carnivores (like, "No carnivores like to eat Border Collies"), then after tasting, the preferences may form.

Comment: @MartinArrJay The reason they don't go for fish is that some of them are going for fish, but there are so many of them that these ones are being crowded out of the seas.

Comment: After the edit: what's the most likely thing to be at the coast of... *all over the world*? It went from open ended to too broad...

Comment: @VLAZ could you give me some sensible restrictions? I guess I could say that the arctic circle is a no-go, but that still leaves a huge area. Any tips?

Comment: @MarkGardner Maybe if you could tell us a bit about the creature's biology other than its carnivorous nature. Also, how have marine biologists missed this behemoth of a creature's existence if they are so large. it doesn't strike me as a particularly subtle creature (unless your world is less scientifically advanced, regard the last point as unsaid if so.)

Comment: @Hyfnae well, they know it exists, but have been ignoring it. They don't know that it is amphibious.

Comment: [This guy from Bay Watch](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/baywatch/images/3/39/Mitch_1.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20151229155745). He hangs out near the water a lot and that face really provokes monster attacks. On a more serious note, this can't be answered.

Comment: Seabirds are too small. Whale do eat krill, but not one at a time. And most megafauna are far enough away from the beach as to be inaccessible. This thing eats people. Beachgoers. Night-time beach parties, perhaps even a concert (hasn't Metallica done performed at a beach a few times?). Though now we're veering into Metalocalypse territory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pretty much anything made out of meat.**

Gathering from them acting from biological imperatives, a radical change of behavior in a species like this is very likely sheer desperation. Humans are the most prolific predators on Earth. We empty our seas of fish and these aquatic residents are fed up... or actually, not fed at all but still desperate to get their fill.

Evolutionary speaking, the creature hasn't left its terrestrial lifestyle long enough to eliminate its terrestrial abilities, even if it hasn't shown any interest in it before. Thus allowing it to walk on the surface. When hungry enough, people and animals will eat whatever they can sink their teeth in.

I want to make one little caveat here. If your creatures are biologically motivated, it tends to be a more gradual process. Isolated events at first when issues start manifesting which increase in frequency as an undesirable situation persists or worsens.

Answer (score 0):

Does it want to eat? It could attack big mamals easy to find.

Is it in fear, pain, angry? It could attack any light and sound sources, that means cars, buildings, etc.